# Error Says "Expected :" in Image Upload Capability

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to create an image upload capability in my app.

In the last line of this bit of code I am getting an error that says "expected :"

Any ideas what I should do to resolve it?

```
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; 
boundary=%@",boundary];

[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rn--%@rn",boundary] 
dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Below is where I get the error:

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; 
name="userfile"; filename="ipodfile.jpg"rn"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotes in the string.

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; 
name="userfile"; filename="ipodfile.jpg"rn"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

With

```
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Single quotes instead of your inner double quotes

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data;  name='userfile'; filename='ipodfile.jpg'rn"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 0):

`"` (double quote) is the **escape character** in **objective-c**(and even in c and c++) and escape character are character combinations that comprise a backslash ("`\`") followed by some character. They are called escape sequences because the backslash causes an "**escape**" from the normal way characters are interpreted by the compiler.

so simply, to define a string in a objective-c , you need that string inside `@""` and what if the `"` (double quote) sign is already there in the string. In that case compiler take that `"` (double quote) sign (that is actually a part of string) as ending of string. So in such situation we need to tell compiler that escape that character. so that reason ahead of escape character we use backslash ("`\`").

in your case you can use backslash ("`\`") as...

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"rn"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: The backslash is the escape character, not the double-quote.